# Как быть с экранами смартфонов и background-image

Tags: javascript, html, css3

Есть проблема: делаю ресайз header-а по высоте окна:

```
function wResize() {
    $('header').css('height', $(window).height());
};

wResize();
```

Это хорошо работает на больших и высоких экранах, но как только тестирую на экранах поменьше - возникает "выпадение" контента из background-image и получается некрасиво, примеры прикладываю:

[image: Пример 1] Пример 1

[image: Пример 2] Пример 2

[image: Пример 3] Пример 3, здесь всё хорошо помещается

Как в таком случае поступать? Если не делать ресайз, то header, в котором всё находится будет ресайзиться по контенту, и скакать при переключении табов, это некрасиво, вот сам header:

```
header
min-height: 640px
background-image: url('../img/top_bg.jpg')
background-position: top center
background-size: cover
color: white
padding-top: 32px
padding-bottom: 40px
```

Answer (score 0):

Не ясно что там за `header` такой, что его не растянуть css'ом, но если только js'ом, я бы начал с:

```
function wResize() {
    $('header').css('height', $(document).height()); // нужна высота документа, а не окна
};

wResize();
```

Comment: Спасибо, то, что искал

Comment: Хотя немного не до конца, в вашем решении, насколько я понимаю, header будет основным контейнером, так как его высота будет по высоте документа, но это слишком много. Как быть в таком случае?

Comment: не знаю что значит "основным контейнером", но явно нужны дополнительные вводные, что бы продолжать разбираться с вашим вопросом, потому что не ясно чего в итоге вы хотите добиться. Я думал у вас header имеет абсолютное позиционирование и вы хотите его просто растянуть на высоту всего контента, но судя по исходникам что вы скинули это не так, так что требуется более точна информация что нужно сделать.

Comment: Мне бы хотелось, чтобы при переключении табов background-image header-а не скакал, это первое, второе - как это можно сделать

Comment: охохой ... я бы сказал, что тут скорее надо с самими табами работать (контейнеру высоту задавать максимальной высоты контента), но это бутстрап который я терпеть не могу .... разбираться с этим сегодня я точно не хочу, лучше сними галочку решенного вопроса (мой ответ тут явно неверен при такой постановке задачи) и пускай кто-то ещё поможет.

Comment: решил через min-height в скрипте, вместо height, min-height получается по высоте окна, но реальная высота оказывается равной высоте контента и остается необходимый padding снизу, я, если честно, не очень понимаю, почему это происходит, но работает на всех разрешениях, сделал в итоге вот так вот, чтобы header не был большим для больших экранов: 
function wResize() {
        $("header").css("min-height", ($(window).height())/2);
    };
    wResize();

Comment: Тогда это должно работать и без скрипта вовсе. Я думал суть в том, что бы бекграунд "не скакал", но если я правильно понимаю, то min-height не решает этой проблемы. Хотя конечно сложновато судить.

Comment: Думал, что решил, оказалось, что похоже нет) именно скачки background-а, в общем пока так как выше скинул всё

Comment: Правильно сделал, что снял галку, может гуру бутстрапа что подскажут .... но лично я бы просто написал свой блок с той же логикой, но без "скачков" ...

Comment: Пока решил проблему только заданием min-height: 340px для блока с галочками, ну или иначе wrapper-а, в идеале тут решается заданием min-height как максимального из всех высот табов по содержимому, но типо это для меня сложно...

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте в CSS header`a `background-attachment: fixed`

Comment: не помогло, добавил

Comment: приложите url сайта или код на jsfiddle

Comment: много библиотек и файлов на локальном сервере, боюсь jsfiddle просто не поймёт, не знаю, куда можно залить

Comment: Можете в браузере сохранить страницу в отдельную папку и скинуть через dropmefiles.com

Comment: http://dropmefiles.com/Y2mXo - сделал, как вы сказали, там index и вспомогательные файлы

Comment: Мда... Сохранилось как надо... Ну и ладно